# First time home owner, off center range hood, trying to replace cooktop?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, range, hood

I recently moved into my first house from an apartment and one of the big selling points was the kitchen.  I love to cook and really want my kitchen to be a place I enjoy, as cooking is my main at-home hobby.  I also want to be able to do high heat cooking that gets a little smokey, so I may be overly picky here.

The main thing is that for some reason the range hood was installed *way* off center back from the range, and seems like it was centered to the middle of the island countertop instead (for aesthetics?).  I know being slightly back is normal, but this is more than that, the vents are 8-10inches back from the front of the range and pretty small.  Theres a big aesthetic glass piece makes it look further forward than it is. This wouldn’t be an issue but the only large burner is pressed against the very front right of the cooktop, and the burners directly below the hood are so tiny they’re practically unusable.  When I’ve tried cooking in a cast iron using the large burner in the front, the smoke barely goes into the vent because half is able to be sucked backwards but the other half wafts away.  Smoke from the small back burners directly under the hood gets sucked up perfectly, but they’re too small to use for much.

My question is if there’s any way to change this without it being a big expense?  One thing I’m taking into account while coming up with a solution is that I’d love to switch to an induction cooktop, but the electric range is literally brand new (still had plastic inside the oven when I moved in) so it seems like money down the drain to take it out.

Here were some of my ideas, feel free to call them stupid:

1. Can I just switch out the cooktop of my range without replacing the whole range? My assumption is that this is kind of janky but is it doable? There are induction cooktops with the large burner further back, which would alleviate the hood placement issue.
2. Should I just use a portable induction cooktop on top of my range until I have the money to switch out the whole range? Our kitchen outlets share a 20amp circuit with the hood, the clothing washing machine in the garage, and the fridge, so this seems to not be an option for our electric IMO.
3. Do I have no real options until I have the money to replace the whole range? Am I being picky enough that what I want is a luxury that requires money to back it up (I know induction is expensive)?  Is there a way to get any money back out of the existing range if I were to replace it? Like I said, it was new when I moved in.

I guess the most pressing of those is if #1 is viable, and if there’s any way to recoup money on the existing range if I were to replace it.

This was long winded, but I appreciate any advice!

Comment: #1 will probably not work.  I think most ranges(oven and cook top) are build together and not made for change.  Is this a newer house or an older(1990s) one?  The shared circuit says older.  A newer range should be worth something, if enough or not is a guess.

Comment: It could have been an uncooperative ceiling joist that caused the strange placement. Is there an additional floor of the house above the range hood? Or is the attic above the range hood? Where does it vent to the outside (if it's not filtering recirculated air)?

Comment: Is the cooktop a drop-in unit separate from an oven? If so, would rotating it by 180 degrees be an option?

Comment: I had an undersized hood in an apt, and I would attach a flexible cutting mat with magnets to it while doing fried chicken and whatnot. That fixed it about 80%; it was almost useless otherwise.

Comment: Pictures (of the stove, the hood, and the two of them together) would be very helpful. There are a lot of variables here that we don't know.

Comment: The type of cooking surface on a *range* typically cannot be swapped—you'd need to swap the whole range.  +1 on pictures.

Answer (score 5):

You can probably get 50%-70% of new cost by reselling your "used, nearly new" range by some local means (classified ads, craigslist, facebook marketplace, kijiji if you're in Canada, etc.) - if you aim higher than that don't expect it to go quickly, if ever - folks need a reason to be willing to take a used item rather than paying a little more for new. Probably best if you leave it in place until it sells so full functionality can be demonstrated.

Replacing the top of the range - I sincerely doubt it. Could be a thing in some alternate universe, but unless you want to start the company it hasn't happened so far in this one, that I'm aware of, other than perhaps some commercial ranges that can be customized.

The option you don't appear to be considering is a larger hood, if the range otherwise suits. Or maybe reinstalling the same hood spaced further forward (lack of pictures makes coming up with reasonable options more difficult.)

Comment: Just came back to comment about changing the hood.  That will probably be the best option.

Comment: Thanks! I think the main reason I was looking into swapping the range instead of the hood was just because I’d be able to switch to induction at the same time, but noted that switching the hood would likely be a more efficient fix.

Comment: So, see if you get any bites on local sales sites for this one if you *want* an induction range.

Comment: +1 to ‘get a powerful hood’ that covers the elements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming from your description that you don't mean off-center left to right, but off-center front to back.

Have you looked into simply remounting the range hood?

I'd been dissatisfied with how far back my range hood was since I moved into my house, and when I replaced the cabinets, I took the opportunity to remount the range hood 3" further away from the back wall than before.  Depending on the depth of your cabinets and the direction of your exhaust ducting, this might be an option for you.

[image]

The yellow arrows are pointing to the stainless blocking plate I added to fill the space.  I believe I purchased it from Amazon - it was originally a generic space-filler intended to help install a drop-in range in a wrong-size hole.  The color match isn't 100% perfect, but it is barely noticeable.  Much cheaper than replacing the range hood with a deeper one.

I attached it to the range hood with industrial double-sided tape.  The wood block is just there to hold it in place while the adhesive sets.